# Word_tokenize, How to print only first token

Tags: python, xml, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to print only 1 token of the entire text but it displays only first letter of the 0 index.

Kindly do let me know where I am wrong.

Here's my code:

```
sen = input("Enter Your sentence - ")
print(sen)

print(word_tokenize(sen[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print(word_tokenize(sen)[0])
```

First tokenize, then pick the first element, instead of first picking the first element of the string (will only be one letter) and then try to tokenize that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sen = input("Enter Your sentence - ")
print(sen)
words = word_tokenize(sen)
print(words[0])
```